# transfer a dic with a list in it into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api

I am reading an API and trying to transfer the response into a dataframe. The response I am getting is a dic with a list in it and I am not sure how to handle that

{'instance_id': -1, 'segment_id': 9000001395, 'list 1': [0.0, 100.0, 0.0], 'list 2': [0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'v85': 11.5}

I have already tried the below but I am getting an error saying that the length of values does not match the length of the index:

```
data=pd.DataFrame(result,index=[0])
```

I am trying to get the data in this shape:

| instance_id | segment_id | list 1 | list 2 | v85 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 9000001395 | [0.0, 100.0, 0.0] | [0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0] | 11.5 |

Comment: Given the response you're getting from the API, would you be able to update your question and show what you would want the table (or pandas df) to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because Pandas is attempting to create a column for each item in your `result` dictionary. The key of each item is used as the column label, the value is used as the list of values. The problem comes where columns are created that have different lengths.

Instead you can just do `df = pd.DataFrame([result])`. Putting the dictionary inside a list means Pandas expects a list of rows. Your list only has a single element, so a single row is created.

Comment: Good to see a simple solution. I'll update myself @OD1995

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pd.DataFrame`, use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` and set `orient` argument as `index` and apply transpose to the obtained dataframe

**CODE**

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient="index").transpose()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware of the orient function - will need to read a bit about it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to transpose, you can directly load the dict as a list containing a dict this way:

```
data=pd.DataFrame([result])
```